# SoundManager2 onplay event configuration does not work

Tags: javascript, audio, google-analytics, soundmanager2

I use [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) for playing sounds on my web sites.

Now I'd like to send a Google Analytics Event each time the user plays a sound.

SoundManager2's documentation says that you can catch the "on play" event via setting a property but when using the [360-ui-player](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/360-player/), this does not work.

I initialize the SoundManager2 like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app/sm/360/360player.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/app/sm/flashblock.css" />

<script src="/app/sm/360/berniecode-animator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/app/sm/soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/app/sm/360/360player.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  soundManager.url = '/app/sm/swf/';
  threeSixtyPlayer.config = {
    playNext: false, 
    autoPlay: false, 
    allowMultiple: false,
    loadRingColor: '#ccc',
    playRingColor: '#AB3C2E',
    backgroundRingColor: '#eee',
    animDuration: 500,
    onplay: function() {
      alert('Playing!'); // DOES NOT WORK!
    },
    animTransition: Animator.tx.veryBouncy
  }        
</script>
```

**Does anyone have a working solution to this?**

I read about solutions where people changed the createSound() function in the SoundManager source code, but I would love to see a solution without changing the library as such.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Having the same problem myself.

Comment: Nope, still waiting for any fruitful comments... I'll update the question and resolve it as soon as I get it working...

Comment: Thanks bas.. Saw a few people having the same issue on the soundmanager forums. Consensus seems to be to edit 360player.js which seems icky..

Comment: @FergalMoran : yes saw that too but I don't want to change 360player.js , as after a version upgrade you have to patch it again and again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Today I had a similar problem with my "onplay" callback set in the defaultOptions of soundmanager2, which wasn't called by soundmanager2 when 360player played a song.

I found out that 360player.js calls `soundManager.createSound()` specifying its own "onplay" callback (the `threeSixtyPlayer.events.play()` function), thus overriding my default callback.

Also, beware: there is no `threeSixtyPlayer.config.onplay` property to set for what I saw.

A non-invasive solution should be to encapsulate callbacks, something like:

```
var onplay360 = threeSixtyPlayer.events.play;

var myOnplay = function(){
  ... your stuff... ;
  onplay360.apply(this); // forces the scope to 'this' = the sound object
};

threeSixtyPlayer.events.play = myOnplay;
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers, 
   Marco

Comment: Also, I have just found out that event `play` is triggered only once! At the start of playing of the song. Event pause is triggered with every pause of playing. But you have to also define event **`resume`** if you want it to work when user pauses and resumes playing several times. Just duplicate block of your code for `play` event and name it `resume`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I searched for answers but it seems there is not much if any documentation about 360player.js.  I guess you just have to study the code.  I tried Marco's method but that did not work for me.  What actually worked for me was much simpler.

```
threeSixtyPlayer.events.play = function(){ 
    //Do Something here like...
    alert('Are you serious?');
}
```

This should give you a head start.  I'm sure the other events can be hooked into this way as well.